# Thread-Safe way to access EclipsePreferences (Project)

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am currently developing an Eclipse-RCP application that stores per-project preferences using the **EclipsePreference** mechanism through **ProjectScope**. At first this seemed to work very well, but we have run into trouble when (read-) accessing these preferences in multithreaded scenarios while at the same time changes are being made to the workspace. What appears to be praticularly problematic is accessing such a preference node (`ProjectScope.getNode()`) while the project is being deleted by an asynchronous user action (right click on Project -> Delete Project). In such cases we get a pretty mix of

- `org.osgi.service.prefs.BackingStoreException`
- `java.io.FileNotFoundException`
- `org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException`

Essentially they all complain that the underlying file is no longer there.

Initial attempts to *fix* this using checks like `IProject.exists()` or `isAccessible()` and even going so far as checking the presence of the actual .prefs file were as futile as expected: They only make the exceptions less likely but do not really prevent them.

So my question is: How are you supposed to safely access things like `ProjectScope.getNode()`? Do you need to go so far to put every read into a `WorkspaceJob` or is there some other, clever way to prevent the above problems like putting the read access in `Display.asyncExec()`?

Although I tried, I did not really find answers to the above question in the Eclipse documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually [scheduling rules](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2Fjobs%2FISchedulingRule.html) are used to concurrently access resources in the workspace.

I've never worked with `ProjectScope`ed preferences but if they are stored within a project or its metadata, then a scheduling rule should help to coordinate access. If you are running the preferences access code in a Job, then setting an appropriate scheduling rule should do:

For example:

```java
IProject project = getProjectForPreferences( projectPreferences );
ISchedulingRule rule = project.getWorkspace().getRuleFactory().modifyRule( project );
Job job = new Job( "Access Project Preferences" ) {
  @Override
  protected IStatus run( IProgressMonitor monitor ) {
    if( project.exists() ) {
      // read or write project preferences
    }
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
};
job.setRule( rule );
job.schedule();
```

The code acquires a rule to modify the project and the Job is guaranteed to run only when no other job with a conflichting rule runs.

If your code isn't running within a job, you can also manually acquire a lock with `IJobManager.beginRule()` and `endRule()`.

For example:

```java
ISchedulingRule rule = ...;
try {
  jobManager.beginRule( rule, monitor );
  if( project.exists() ) {
    // read or write project preferences
  }
} finally {
  jobManager.endRule( rule );
}
```

As awkward as it looks, the call to `beginRule` **must** be within the try block, see the [JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2Fjobs%2FISchedulingRule.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply, that kind of solution was exactly what I had in mind and it works perfectly for the EclipsePreferences API (It survived stresstest using UI-automation with QF-Test).